# How should I implement application-wide font size setting and dialog allowing a user to select that font size?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, settings

I need to implement Options dialog, allowing user to change font size (and some more parameters). How should I do this if these settings should be application-wide, and somehow globally bounded to all controls, without copy-pasting binding to these settings in every view?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a style for your controls in which you bind these properties via DynamicResource to a value definied in some ResourceDictionary merged with your App.xaml. This value can then be altered by Application.Current.Resources["Key"].